# Перевести sql запрос в Laravel с помощью Eloquent ORM или Query Builder

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Есть 3 таблицы (`CAT_OBL, CAT_STATION, TOS_MES`), 1-я и 2-я связаны между собой по полю OBL_ID, 2-я и 3-я таблицы связанны по полю IND_ST. Нужно вывести данные из 3-й таблицы и вывести значения полей для неё из 1-й и 2-й таблицы. Есть сырой mysql-запрос , однако не могу перенести его на Eloquent ORM. Сам запрос: `select c.obl_id,  c.ind_st, tm.*
  from TOS_MES tm, CAT_STATION c, CAT_OBL o  where ((c.ind_st = tm.ind_st) and ( c.obl_id=o.obl_id))`

Answer (score 0):

Переделайте запрос на джойны:

```
select c.obl_id, c.ind_st, tm.* from TOS_MES tm join 
CAT_STATION c on  c.ind_st = tm.ind_st   join CAT_OBL o 
o on c.obl_id=o.obl_id;
```

Вот пример джойнов на qb:

```
$users = DB::table('users')
    ->join('contacts', 'users.id', '=', 'contacts.user_id')
    ->join('orders', 'users.id', '=', 'orders.user_id')
    ->select('users.*', 'contacts.phone', 'orders.price')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Суть в том, что нужно именно через модели это сделать :(

Answer (score 0):

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function contacts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Contact');
    }
    public function orders()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Order');
    }
}

$users = App\User::all();
$contacts = $users->contacts();
$orders= $users->orders();
```